# Xamarin iOS firebase issue

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

As part of my project I'm working on firebase cloud messaging for iOS. Partly my issue is as follows: the iOS app's AppDelegate contains the following code:

```
        // Monitor token generation
        InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh((sender, e) =>
        {
            // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
            // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
            // should be done.
            var refreshedToken = InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
            Console.WriteLine(refreshedToken);

            if (refreshedToken != null)
            {
                if (credentialsService.Email.Equals("") && credentialsService.Password.Equals(""))
                {
                    credentialsService.SaveCredentials(refreshedToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    credentialsService.SaveCredentials(credentialsService.Email, credentialsService.Password, refreshedToken, credentialsService.Token);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error, token is empty");
            }
        });
```

This callback function will be called whenever a token is necessary. The credentialsService will then be used to collect that token and send it to the server when the user logs in. The problem is, however, that the token is not immediately ready. The android version of this (works almost identical) will be assigned a token before the splash screen of this app is loaded. The iOS app however takes a significant amount of time (roughly 20-30 seconds) before a token is generated. The user can log it already at this time and any token that is generated after that will only be sent to the server once the user relogs.

Is there any solution to make sure the token is generated faster? I do get the following errors, which are not uncommon on the internet. However, googling for solutions didn't really help.

> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
>
> FIRMessaging registration is not ready with auth credentials

Thank you,
Riccardo

Comment: same issue someone helps?..

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but is ugly:

```
            while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            _taskToken.Wait(1000);
            this.token = InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
        }
```

you can wait for refresh after 60 or 90 seconds and then get the token..